# Do not show animations when selection on C3.js chart is made

Tags: c3.js, c3

Is it possible to remove animations when I select data point on C3.js chart? I have selection enabled and duration set to 0, but it does not work - when I click on point animation is still made. My code:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
        ], selection: {enabled:true}
    }, transition:  {duration: 0}
});
chart.select(['data1'], [1,3,5]);
```

Thanks for every help!
Martin

Answer (score 3):

You're using `chart.transition`, which is used for specifying the time/delay used when (eg) animating an addition of data to the chart.

What you're wanting is the `point.focus.expand.enabled` property, see:
http://c3js.org/reference.html#point-focus-expand-enabled

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jrdsxvys/7/